# sbt migration from 0.13.0 to 1.3.0

Tags: scala, sbt

I am getting error while migrating sbt from 0.13.0 to 1.3.0. I am currently facing issue in error: not found: value scriptClasspath.

My build.sbt file after the migration.

```
val main = (project in file(".")).
     settings(
        appName         = "polaris",
        appVersion      = "1.strong text8.8",
        //scriptClasspath := Seq("modules/*", "customer-modules/*")
       // scriptClasspath = Seq[File] = file("modules/*") :: ("customer-modules/*") :: Nil
        **scriptClasspath** ~= { cp => cp.+:("modules/*").+:("customer-modules/*") }
    ).dependsOn(
       core, addressbook, pbx, pbxAppSoftphones, pbxAppCallLog, pbxAppQueues, pbxAppPhonebook, pbxAppClick2dial, pbxAppOperator
    ).aggregate(
       core, addressbook, pbx, pbxAppSoftphones, pbxAppCallLog, pbxAppQueues, pbxAppPhonebook, pbxAppClick2dial, pbxAppOperator
    )
```

and also I have attached plugin.sbt file below -

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn


// The Typesafe repository
//resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

//resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.6")
```

What wrong am I doing while migration? there is a syntax error I am not able to figure out.

Comment: do you have this `plugins.sbt` file in the `project/` folder? where does this `scriptClasspath` come from?

Comment: Yes, the `plugins.sbt` is under `project` folder and `scriptClasspath` comes from `build.sbt` under `project` folder.


and as per the below sbt guide, I changed the file name from `Build.scala` to `build.sbt`

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html

Comment: `build.sbt` should be in the root folder, not `project/`. and it's `scriptedClasspath` not `scriptClasspath`, I think

Comment: Hi @laughedelic, thanks for your reply.
But I have already tried this and I get error -

`error: value +: is not a member of sbt.io.PathFinder
scriptedClasspath ~= { cp => "modules/" +: "customer-modules/" +: cp }`
^

Comment: Hi @laughedelic, currently I am getting error as below -


`scriptClasspath ~= { cp => cp :+ "modules/" :+ "customer-modules/" }
[error] References to undefined settings: 
[error] 
[error]   core / buildInfo from core / Compile / sourceGenerators (/polaris_sbt_upgrade_1.3.0/polaris-upgrade-sbt/modules/core/build.sbt:32)
[error] 
[error]   scriptClasspath from scriptClasspath (/polaris_sbt_upgrade_1.3.0/polaris-upgrade-sbt/build.sbt:49)
[error]`

Comment: You should add these details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first error that looks like a lead:

> error: value +: is not a member of sbt.io.PathFinder scriptedClasspath ~= { cp => "modules/" +: "customer-modules/" +: cp }

It says that `scriptedClasspath` is a `PathFinder` and you're trying to add elements to it as if it was a `Seq[String]`.

Read the docs on how to work with [Path Finders](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Paths.html#Path+Finders) and see the [Scaladoc](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/io/PathFinder.html) for the `PathFinder` type.

Most probably you will need to adjust it to something like

```scala
scriptedClasspath ~= { pathFinder => 
  pathFinder +++
  (baseDirectory.value / "modules") +++ 
  (baseDirectory.value / "customer-modules")
}
```

Comment: Hi @laughedelic,

I am able to fix this issue now. I tried like this by referring the docs you provided and it worked.

`def scriptedClasspath (base:File) : PathFinder = (base / "modules") +++ (base / "customer-modules")`